# unix remove duplicates with swapped names

Tags: awk

Here is a file with duplicate data in column1 and 2 swapped at different places.

```
$ cat partnership.dat
V_Kohli|Yuvraj_Singh|57
PA_Patel|CH_Gayle|5
CH_Gayle|V_Kohli|18
MA_Starc|S_Rana|14
S_Rana|MA_Starc|14
V_Kohli|CH_Gayle|18
CH_Gayle|PA_Patel|5
Yuvraj_Singh|V_Kohli|57
V_Kohli|AB_de_Villiers|61
AB_de_Villiers|V_Kohli|61
S_Rana|AB_de_Villiers|5
AB_de_Villiers|S_Rana|5
```

I'm trying to remove the duplicates and get the below data

```
V_Kohli|Yuvraj_Singh|57
PA_Patel|CH_Gayle|5
CH_Gayle|V_Kohli|18
MA_Starc|S_Rana|14
V_Kohli|AB_de_Villiers|61
S_Rana|AB_de_Villiers|5
```

The below awk command is listing all the records.

```
awk -F"|" ' NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;b[$2$1]=$3;next} ($2$1 in b) { print }' partnership.dat partnership.dat
```

Can this be fixed?.

Comment: wrt `b[$2$1]` - you can't create a unique value by concatenating 2 strings since `a bc` and `ab c` both concatenate to `abc`. You need to provide a separator between the strings, e.g. `b[$2 FS $1]` (or use RS or SUBSEP or OFS or something else depending on your needs for that value in the rest of the script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic awk approach uses half as much memory as using the fields as 2 different array indices in their different possible orders:

```
$ awk -F'|' '!seen[$1>$2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1]++' file
V_Kohli|Yuvraj_Singh|57
PA_Patel|CH_Gayle|5
CH_Gayle|V_Kohli|18
MA_Starc|S_Rana|14
V_Kohli|AB_de_Villiers|61
S_Rana|AB_de_Villiers|5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply group the file by making making an hash map, with keys taken out of `$1 $2` and then with `$2 $1`. This way we uniquely identify a line only if it is unique irrespective of order of `$1` and `$2`

```
awk -F'|' '!unique[$1 FS $2]++ && !unique[$2 FS $1]++' partnership.dat
```

Comment: Or `awk -F'|' '!(unique[$1 FS $2]++ || unique[$2 FS $1]++)' file`

Comment: @Jotne: Yes De Morgan's Law

Comment: That uses twice as much memory as necessary, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57254014/1745001.